# Increment and insert values based on a specific value of another array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code with the given arrays `a` and `b`.

```
import numpy as np

# Parts of interest are highlighted with ^ ...

a = np.array([0,2,9,12,18,19])
#                   ^^    ^^
b = np.array([1,1,1,2,1,3]
#                   ^   ^
# Should result in an array like
assert result == np.array([0,2,9,12,13,18,19,20,21])
#                                ^^ ^^    ^^ ^^ ^^
```

The values in `b` define how many increments of the value in `a` (at the same index) should be inserted in the result. Ones in `b` don't affect the result. I think that I could do some splitting/joining and use a loop. But I'm wondering if this can be solved with numpy functions and good performance?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are the values of `a` different? For example, is it possible that `a = [1,1], b=[2,2]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang The values of `a` are unique (in ascending order), the values of `b` might be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's a vectorized one -

```
def intervaled_ranges(ar, start=0):
    # Vectorized way to create ranges given sizes for each group
    c = ar.cumsum()
    v = -ar+1
    l = ar.sum()

    i = np.ones(l, dtype=int)
    i[c[:-1]] = v[:-1]
    i[0] = start
    return i.cumsum()

out = np.repeat(a,b)+intervaled_ranges(b)
```

**Approach #2 :** We can incorporate `a` into the intervaled-formation and hence skip the `repeat` step and achieve better performance, like so -

```
c = b.cumsum()
v = -b+1
s = b.sum()
i = np.ones(s, dtype=a.dtype)
i[c[:-1]] = v[:-1]+np.diff(a)
i[0] = a[0]
out = i.cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listcomp:

```
[k for i, j in zip(a, b) for k in range(i, i + j)]
# [0, 2, 9, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score -1):

If `pandas` is an option:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':a})
(d['a'].add(d.loc[d.index.repeat(b)]
            .groupby(level=0)
            .cumcount())
       .values
)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  2,  9, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21], dtype=int64)
```